# Finding same integer ranges that are in two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, range

I'm trying to find the index and length of ranges that consist of two or more adjacent numbers in an array that might also exist in another array (but might not start at the same indices). Example:

```
var source = new[] {6, 15, 8, 1, 2, 4, 11, 21};
var target = new[] {8, 1, 2, 4, 15, 11, 21, 6};
```

These two arrays differ but both posses two equal ranges of two adjacent numbers `[1, 2]` and `[11, 21]`. I want to write a function that can find the start index and length of such ranges in the source array (in this case index 3, length 2 for the first and index 6, length 2 for the second).

My initial approach would probably be to write nested loops that iterate over every field in both arrays and compare them but that would quickly turn into a performance killer with large arrays. Is there any useful LINQ API or other method to find these values?

Comment: And what about `{8, 1, 2, 4}`

Comment: The problem is called [Longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

Comment: @DragandDrop right, didn't see that one!

Comment: @xanatos Thanks for the helpful comment! This at least gives me a name I can search for.

Answer (score 1):

This has not been optimized for performance in any way. I believe you could possibly use some type of substring search optimization ([Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm)?) to improve the performance.

In general, a LINQ solution will not be more efficient than a procedural solution, especially when working with arrays, where indexing is fast.

Using a couple of extension methods, you can find all the common subsequences. First, an extension method that generates all possible subsequences for a sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Subsequences<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src) => 
    Enumerable.Range(0, src.Count() - 1)
              .Select(k => src.Skip(k))
              .SelectMany(s1s => Enumerable.Range(2, s1s.Count() - 1).Select(k => s1s.Take(k)));
```

This works by generating all sequences (of at least length 2) by skipping over increasing number of beginning items, and then generating all subsequences of those sequences by dropping increasing numbers of items from the end.

Using the two parameter `Select` method, you can remember the position of each item for later. I convert to a `List` so the sub sequence generation is a little more efficient when calling `Count`:

```
var s1ps = s1.Select((n,i) => (n,i)).ToList().Subsequences();
var s2ps = s2.Select((n,i) => (n,i)).ToList().Subsequences();
```

Now, you can find all the matching subsequences from the sources. Then you can group the matches by their starting position in the original source, and keep the longest match, and group by the ending position and keep the longest match. To help with this, use an extension method that groups an `IEnumerable` by a key function, and then keeps the maximum based on a value function:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MaximumMatch<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T,TKey> keyFn, Func<T,int> valueFn) =>
    src.GroupBy(keyFn).Select(sg => sg.OrderByDescending(s => valueFn(s)).First());
```

With this extension applied twice, you get all the longest matching subsequences:

```
var ans = s1ps.SelectMany(as1p => s2ps.Where(as2p => as1p.Count() == as2p.Count()).Where(as2p => as1p.Select(sp => sp.n).SequenceEqual(as2p.Select(sp => sp.n))).Select(as2p => (as1p,as2p)))
                .MaximumMatch(st => st.as1p.First().i, st => st.as1p.Count())
                .MaximumMatch(st => st.as1p.Last().i, st => st.as1p.Count())
                .Select(stg => new { s1begin = stg.as1p.First().i, s1end = stg.as1p.Last().i, s2begin = stg.as2p.First().i, s2end = stg.as2p.Last().i });
```

Finally, you take each matching subsequence and project it to its beginning and ending positions.

Comment: I'm trying to use your suggestion but I'm getting errors when using `s1.Select((, i)...`: `error CS8179: Predefined type System.ValueTuple 2 is not defined or imported, or is declared in multiple referenced assemblies`

Comment: ... I should probably try to specify the type argument for Select explicitly. But what type argument does it take? I tried various types of Tuples but it didn't work.

Comment: The code uses the ValueTuple from recent versions of C#. If you are using an older version of .Net, you must use NuGet to add the ValueTuple. Otherwise, just replace the tuple with an anonymous object.

Comment: Thanks @NetMage that error was resolved by switching to Net 4.7.1 but I still get other errors... In your last code block in `sp.n` the n could not be resolved and `stg.as1p stgas2p` cannot be resolved.